# Is it okay to "game" StackExchange?

Tags: discussion

I answered a question on Oct 2014 ([How to get name of calling function/method in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2110732/how-to-get-name-of-calling-function-method-in-php/26318820#26318820)). While an accepted answer was already chosen, I believed my method was better...

... But my answer never got any traction. Only 9 points on a popular question. I wondered why. Was it a bad answer?

No. As it turns out, someone edited an inferior (but high-ranking) answer to copy mine. And he also never credited or even up-voted my answer. This copied answer now has 114 points, while mine is stuck at 9.

This guy has 12.3k points, so I’m betting he’s done this before.

I checked his profile, and see that he sometimes edits 5 or more posts a day. I picked one edit at random, and saw there too, he edited a high-ranking answer, but only contributed info that was already provided in another low-ranking answer.

Is this acceptable practice on StackOverflow?

Comment: He didn't copy your answer. The other answer already did the exact same thing, it was just split into two lines instead of combined into one. Someone edited it to make it one line.

Comment: he also gains no rep for this kind of edit, so not sure what 12.3k rep has to do with this.

Comment: @animuson Actually there's a relevant bit of PHP trivia here. The two-line solution with the temporary variable assignment is a "different" answer in that it is syntactically valid in PHP < 5.4. The one-line solution actually would not have run in the most popular version of PHP being used at that time. So, at that point in time, they *were* very different answers. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20533503/229044

Comment: Though, I just realized your one-line solution was posted *years* later, long after PHP5.4 was commonly available. At that point, rather than posting your "new" solution as a new solution, **you** should have edited the existing duplicate answer to fix its syntax rather than leaving that for somebody else to do.

Comment: The whole system is a game, that is the point.

Comment: PHP at the time supported my method for more than a year. As a new member, I didn't have the ranking to edit posts.

Comment: Poor qustion title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Moral of the story:  **don't assume malice.**

Yes, the user did post a similar answer to yours, but it wasn't a copy.  [The edit history identifies this as such.](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11238046/revisions)

The likely issue is that, due to other viewers' sorting preferences, they likely saw the accepted answer first, *then* the higher voted answer and simply went with the crowd.

Sometimes this happens, but I'm not going to say that the user did it out of any ill will or spite.

I also quickly glanced at their other highly upvoted answers and saw pretty much the same thing - simple and pithy answers; even if other answers had covered similar material, it was expressed in an easier to read form, which is acceptable.

Comment: Agreed, I don't think it was necessarily out of malice.